# Locating nearest Button Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I am trying to click the "Delete Comment" button after finding the comment that contains a specific hashtag, husky, which is a hyperlink.

Since there are multiple "Delete Comment" buttons, I think the best way is to just find the comment that has the hashtag, and then click the nearest button, but I could be wrong there.

In the picture, I want to click the button highlighted below the hashtag, not below:

[image]

So far, I have

```
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="/explore/tags/husky/"]')
```

Which successfully locates the tag, but I am stumped after that.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of html. Insert the html using the snippet tool via [edit]. Then we can actually  do some testing with it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of xpath below.

*Explanation*: find **a** with "#hasky" **text**, get first parent **li** with "menuitem" **role** and get child **button** (with "Delete Comment" **title** attribute):

```
//a[.='#husky']/ancestor::li[@role='menuitem'][1]//button

//a[.='#husky']/ancestor::li[@role='menuitem'][1]//button[@title='Delete Comment']

//a[contains(@href, "/explore/tags/husky/")]/ancestor::li[@role='menuitem'][1]//button

//li[@role='menuitem' and .//a[.='#husky']]//button[@title='Delete Comment']
```

Answer (score -1):

Something simple like

```
//a[.='#husky']//following::button[@title='Delete Comment'][1]
```

should work just fine. If it were me, I would wrap this in a method and pass in the link text to delete the appropriate comment. You can then take the link text and put it into the locator in the place of `#husky`.

```
def delete_comment(comment)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//a[.='{comment}']//following::button[@title='Delete Comment'][1]").click()
```