# How to iterate <td> in table to find specific text using Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, protractor

I have a dynamic table with 2 columns and n number of rows.In the first column there will be a title and in second column it will be the button to go into details of that title.

I want to iterate through each of the row to find specific text title and click on the second column's button of that title.

I tried many ways searching google but couldn't find anything.

The AngularJS code for that in HTML is as below.

```
<table>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="registration in Registrations | orderBy:'title'" class="tableRow ng-scope">
                <td style="padding-left: 20px;" ng-if="reg.title != 'Jabc'" class="ng-binding ng-scope">test</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 20px;">
                <button ng-click="enter(registration)" class="ng-binding">Enter community</button>
            </td>


            <tr ng-repeat="registration in Registrations | orderBy:'title'" class="tableRow ng-scope">
                <td style="padding-left: 20px;" ng-if="reg.title != 'Jabc'" class="ng-binding ng-scope">test1</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 20px;">
                <button ng-click="enter(registration)" class="ng-binding">Enter community</button>
            </td>



            <tr ng-repeat="registration in Registrations | orderBy:'title'" class="tableRow ng-scope">
                <td style="padding-left: 20px;" ng-if="reg.title != 'Jabc'" class="ng-binding ng-scope">test2</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 20px;">
                <button ng-click="enter(registration)" class="ng-binding">Enter community</button>
            </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As shown in the above table there are three rows. I want to select the row by name to suppose "test1" and wants to click on the second column's button of the same row.

Here, I got the index of the specific text I'm looking for by writing below code.

```
    let elm = element.all(by.repeater('registration in myRegistrations'));
    let index;
    elm.getText().then(function(text){
        console.log(text);
        for(var i=0; i<text.length; i++){
            if(text[i] == 'protractor-testing Enter community'){
                index = i;
                console.log('Community found :: ' + text[i]);
            }    
        }

    });

    console.log("Index :: " + index);
```

Now, by this index can I click on the button from the table row = index and second column of the same row?

Below is my whole script.

The conf.js file ..

```
// An example configuration file
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
exports.config = {
    // The address of a running selenium server.
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:' + (process.env.PORT || '9000'),
    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
      browserName: 'chrome'
    },

    params: {
      Firstname: 'virus',
      Lastname: 'virus',
      Email: 'virus@email.com',
      Username: 'virus',
      Password: 'virus',
      TempUsername : 'temp',
      TempPassword: 'temp',
      AdminUsername: 'admin',
      AdminPassword: 'admin',
      CreateTitle: 'protractor-testing',
      CreateKey: 'protractor-testing'
    },
    // Spec patterns are relative to the configuration file location passed
    // to protractor (in this example conf.js).
    // They may include glob patterns.
    // specs: ['../spec/2 Login/spec.js'],
    suites: {
      login: '../spec/2 Login/spec.js'
    },

    // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
      showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.
    },

    // onPrepare: function(){
    //   jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
    //     savePath: '../test/reports'
    //   })
    //   );
    // },
  };
```

Below is my spec.js file

```
describe('Testing', function(){
    it('perform login', function() {}
        browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
        console.log("Admin :: " + browser.params.AdminUsername + " " + browser.params.AdminPassword);
        element(by.model('user.userName')).sendKeys(browser.params.AdminUsername);
        element(by.model('user.password')).sendKeys(browser.params.AdminPassword);
        browser.sleep('2000');
        element(by.buttonText('Login')).click();
        element(by.model("newCommunity.title")).sendKeys(browser.params.CreateTitle);
        element(by.model("newCommunity.key")).sendKeys(browser.params.CreateKey);
        let buttons = element.all(by.css("button.ng-binding"));
        let tds = element.all(by.css("td.ng-binding"));
        console.log("Buttons :: " + buttons);
        console.log("tds :: " + tds);
        // var buttons = driver.findElements(By.css("button.ng-binding"));
        // var tds = driver.findElements(By.css("td.ng-binding"));
        for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
            console.log("get text for index " + i + " Value :: " + tds[i].getText());
            if (tds[i].getText() == 'protractor-testing') {
                console.log("Got the actual community at : " + i);
                console.log("Clicking button :: " + buttons[i]);
                buttons[i].click();
                break;
            }
        }

    });
})
```

Please note that I do not want to use xPath.

Answer (score 1):

Well for one thing I would not personally have elements that are identical (in terms of HTML) on the same page if I can control it.  But to get your element on the HTML shown, the following should work:
                          (I'm writing Javascript because of your protractor tag I'm assuming that's how your tests are written)

```
buttons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button"))
buttons[1].click();
```

However, if you want to find it specifically by the name (for any use case) you could do

```
buttonWithText1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()[contains(., 'test1')]]/following-sibling::td/button");
buttonWithText1.click();
```

As @Sers points out below the xpath `//td[.='test1']/following-sibling::td/button` also works and is the cleanest.  Or shortest, at least.

If you want to dynamically use that xpath to find buttons by that text you could use:

```
var myText = "test1"
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[.='" + myText + "']/following-sibling::td/button).click()
```

## EDIT

**the user has said that they don’t want to use xpath.** Based on the HTML you could use a css selector like this to select the button next to some string myText.

```
var buttons = browser.findElements(By.css(‘button.ng-binding’))
var tds = browser.findElements(By.css(‘td.ng-binding’))
for (i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    if (tds[i].getText()==myText) {
        buttons[i].click()
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also can be `//td[.='test1']/following-sibling::td/button`

Comment: i agree axes are the way to go but button is not a sibling of the td that contains the title text. I think you need will need `//td[.='test1']/parent::tr[1]//button[1]` or else `//td[.='test1']/following::button[1]`

Comment: @DublinDev there're a lot way to do it, all depends on the rest HTML. `//td[.='test1']/following::button[1]` cleanest one

Comment: @DublinDev I think the formatting is a bit funky and they should be siblings (also there's no closing tag on any of the `tr` elements)

Comment: Hi @C. Peck, I want to try your code but driver is undefined it says.

Comment: I tried with element.all instead of driver but it is still not clicking the button.

Comment: @Virus Ok, have you defined the driver as something else (like browser, would be a common one)?  Did you define it at all? Any chance you could paste your whole script into the question so I can get some context for what’s happening here?

Comment: *I tried with element.all instead of driver but it is still not clicking the button* .  Well, if driver is not defined, it’s definitely not going to be able to interact with the browser!

Comment: @C.Peck Please see my attached conf.js and spec.js files

Comment: @Virus Aha! I forgot that protractor could take care of some of the webdriver stuff behind the scenes. And it turns out my first supposition is correct—your webdriver is simply called “browser” where I had assumed it was (the thing I always use), “driver”. Give it a shot with my latest edit. I have somewhat higher hopes this round!

Comment: @C.Peck Test case passes but It is not clicking the button and redirecting to a different page which I'm able to do manually.

Comment: Does it ever get inside the if statement for the console to print these two lines?

 `console.log("Got the actual community at : " + i);
  console.log("Clicking button :: " + buttons[i]);`

Comment: @Virus As a secondary point, if you are intending to test that the button redirects to another page, you need to add an assertion or expectation for that to happen.  Case in point: you were unable to click the button and go to another page and the testcase **still passed**.  Just thought I'd mention that in case you are wanting to confirm successful navigation after the button click.

Comment: No, It doesn't print the anything inside for loop

Comment: Do you have any idea about What if I say that I put the test1 data at last row always and is there any simplest way to click the last row 2nd column button?

Comment: That will be easy if we remove the requirement of dynamically finding the button by an adjacent element's text.  Simply


`let buttons = browser.findElements(by.css('button'));
buttons[1].click();`


Or you can substitute `element.all` for `browser.findElements` if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for that help ... But I'm sad that we couldn't have any way to find the text and click respective button.

Comment: Well, the code I wrote should accomplish exactly that, and I think we could get it working on your end if you want to keep trying.  If you want to paste in the latest version of your spec file I'll take a look and see exactly what our options are.  Or if you are ok with this solution, you can just accept my answer and move on.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement not to use xpath seems very restrictive as it is by far the best method for your use case mainly because **locating based on css does not allow you to do exact matching on the tag text**, in your case the title `<td>`s.

To achieve this using css you will have to use some potentially unreliable chained locators such as

```
element(by.cssContainingText('tr','test')).element(by.css('button'));
```

I say unreliable as this locator will actually identify all three of your buttons due to the fact that all three of your title  tag contain the characters 'test'. It works in this case but could cause issue in your actual tests.

I would seriously recommend pushing back on that no xpath requirement and going with the following sibling answer provided by C Peck as that will be the most reliable long term.

Comment: I think you meant to pass ('td','test') into `cssContainingText()` 

There is a problem with using `cssContainingText()`;  for example in the code you have above, (after swapping `'td'` for `'tr'`) it will match all three `td` nodes simply because the strings "test", "test1",  and "test2" all contain "test".

Comment: @C.Peck actually I intended to use `tr`. By using tr it will look at the text from all the elements that are a child of the tr tag, including the title and button tags. Then we can chain on another locator which can find a child (the button). If we used `td` we would not be able chain locators as both `td`s are siblings on the same node. Also I addressed that potential issue with `cssContainingText` in my answer but wanted to provide a potential solution to OP could try if not using xpath is really an unavoidable constraint.

Comment: Well, I dunno how I missed that explanation but there it is, oops.  Anyhow, regarding `cssContainingText` what makes you say *By using tr it will look at the text from all the elements that are a child of the tr tag*?  I was looking at the source code and found that `cssContainingText` just passes its arguments to another function, `findByCssContainingText` the `clientSideScripts` file. Here’s what `cssContainingText` returns: `return driver.findElements(By.js(
            clientSideScripts.findByCssContainingText, cssSelector, searchText, using,
            rootSelector));`

Comment: Moving on to the `clientSideScripts`l file, I found the following in the body of the `findByCssContainingText`:                  `var elements = using.querySelectorAll(cssSelector);
  var matches = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    var element = elements[i];
    var elementText = element.textContent || element.innerText || '';
    var elementMatches = searchText instanceof RegExp ?
        searchText.test(elementText) :
        elementText.indexOf(searchText) > -1;

    if (elementMatches) {
      matches.push(element);
    }
  }
  return matches;`

Comment: @C.Peck I can't point you to the piece of code which is responsible for it but I know from experience that calling some of the the element methods on elements which contain sub-elements will run on all of them. I copied down the html code in the question and run some locators locally and what I saw from running `element(by.cssContainingText('tr','test')).getText()` was `test Enter community`

Comment: sorry for the multiple comments due to the character limit and hard-to-read code.  Anyway, my reading of the code here is that **first**, the function evaluates against the DOM the css selector you have passed in and gets an array of matches, which in your case would be all the `tr` elements. **Then** it loops through that array to find any elements whose `textContent` or `innerText` contains the search string.  I don’t see anything that would indicate the search propagates to its children. Am I missing something?

Comment: @C.Peck I think I understand it now. You are correct that finds the `tr` elements only. However when get the elementText var i declared it is getting the text either by `textContent` or `innerText`. Both of these option will return all the text associated with an element + any sub elements. You can test this in chrome dev tools on this page by inspecting an element which has sub elements and running `$0.textContent` or `$0.innerText`. Both should return the displayed text of all sub elements

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to use [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) and barring the `innerHTML` all the other attribute values of the reference `<td>` nodes are identical. Now [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) doesn't supports `innerHTML`, so to locate the *button* adjacent to the element with text as **test1** you can use the following *css-selectors*:

```
"table>tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)>button"
```

Comment: OP wants to do it dynamically and have a css selector that finds the buttons based on the text of the button’s adjacent label—I already offered a solution like yours but they responded that they want to dynamically search based on the innerHTML of the `td`. I’m currently writing up a fairly hacky way to accomplish this.

Comment: I agree with C. Peck.

Comment: @DebanjanB beside the point, but if you're going to use that full css selector you'd be better off with `driver.findElements(By.css('button'))[1].click();`  :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use xpath to achieve your goal:

```
//tr[contains(@class,'tableRow') and ./td[.='test']]//button
```

You can find more examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55119606/locating-nearest-button-selenium-python/55119958#55119958).

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not want to use xPath.

Comment: @Virus why? This is the fastest way to find by text

Comment: I know but My requirements are given and they told not to use xPath.

Comment: @Sers actually xpath is the slowest way to identify an element, with id being the fastest. [here](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/34-xpath-vs-css-revisited-2) you can find actual performance numbers for xpath and css; css was always faster.

Comment: @C.Peck for the case, xpath is much faster, than iterate throw each element. Also even I prefer css, actually between xpath and css there’s no critical differences for test purposes.

Comment: @Sers You say *between xpath and css there’s no critical differences for test purposes.*. I would vehemently disagree there. If you have 3000 test cases to run the performance of xpath can make a huge difference in running time. I’ve also found xpath to generally be more flaky than css which obviously creates more maintenance work.

Comment: @C.Peck It's very unlikely that you will see any noticeable differences in the performance of XPath vs CSS selectors. Those perf numbers were from several years ago. If you test the same (well written) locator in XPath vs CSS selector today, the difference is probably on the <100ms level. You aren't going to see that in a script that touches several pages... let alone even a single page due to inconsistencies in page load times, etc. Also, in my experience locators are only as flaky as they are written. A well written XPath locator isn't any more flaky than the equivalent CSS selector.

Comment: @C.Peck ... having said that... I prefer ID then CSS selectors. I only use XPath when it's absolutely necessary (finding elements by contained text and some DOM traversal). I think CSS selectors are much easier to learn, they are much shorter, there are other advantages like avoiding string matching for class names, etc. I'm told there is better support for CSS selectors on the fringe browsers but I generally don't test on those so it doesn't affect me.

Comment: *I prefer ID then CSS selectors. I only use XPath when it's absolutely necessary (finding elements by contained text and some DOM traversal)* same here; however, I have access to my application's source code so I can add unique ID's wherever I want, so our existing set of tests almost exclusively utilizes ID locators.

On the topic of performance, ID selectors are WAY faster than xpath or css selectors even when they are just `//*[@id = "myId"]` or `#myId` respectively.

Comment: @JeffC Last I checked I was getting elements by ID in ~15 ms vs css selectors which clocked in at 50-60 ms (I didn't bother testing xpath because I hate it and it is not implemented in any tests.  I'm currently maintaining and adding to a suite with ~3000 Selenium test cases, and those numbers compound quickly--say you are locating an average of 5 elements in each test (which I feel is a conservative estimate at least for me), and each one wastes 40 ms due to our selector strategy.  An extra 200 ms per test gives me 10 minutes of wasted time throughout the suite.

Comment: That may not sound like much especially since the whole suite takes a little over 6 hrs when run back-to-back, but I have pretty strict requirements for performance; the UI (and API/back-end) tests are part of a continuous integration pipeline which needs to give developers feedback on commit and merge.  I've been allocated 10 minutes to get all the tests run.  Right now we are shelling out bigtime to SauceLabs to provision enough space for 40 VM's to run our tests in parallel, which brings our run time down to 9.5 - 10 mins unless something crazy happens, we lose connection to the cloud, etc

Comment: @C.Peck no need to continue, nobody says id not the best. For particular case xpath is the way to go✌️ Still waiting your answer for the OP, if you’ll not, I’ll try to do it. I even upvoted your answer already

Comment: @C.Peck From testing I've done in the past, I was finding that CSS selectors were faster than even IDs. I just created a mock HTML file with nothing but `<div id="id"></div>` inside the `BODY` tag. I then wrote a quick Selenium script using C# and ChromeDriver to locate that element 1000 times with `By.Id("id")`, `By.CssSelector("#id")`, and `By.XPath("//*[@id='id']")`. The results surprised even me. I ran each test three times... the first two time the order was the same, the last I moved XPath to go first in case there was some caching or something going on.

Comment: @C.Peck The results were RUN 1
By.Id: 18481
By.CssSelector: 18305
By.XPath: 17940

RUN 2
By.Id: 16145
By.CssSelector: 16288
By.XPath: 16194

RUN 3 (switched order)
By.XPath: 17978
By.CssSelector: 17423
By.Id: 17726

XPath was fastest in RUN 1 and 2nd fastest in RUN 2 and slowest in RUN 3. I was surprised more by how close all three were in each run. Granted this is not a particularly complicated test and YMMV on other browsers (probably more in IE) but you can see how close they are. I still am not a big fan of XPath... :)

Comment: @C.Peck Your suite is impressive btw... 40 VMs on Sauce is not cheap. We used to use them. I would cut the # of VMs in half... no dev needs results back faster than 20 mins... ;) but I love to watch stuff go fast...

Comment: @Sers I did provide a solution by grabbing the `td.ng-binding` elements and looping through them to find the index of the element whose `getText()` matched the desired string. Its ugly but it works.  But OP gave it a shot (I guess?) and it "didn't work".  They gave up on the requirement to pass in the text and use it to  find the adjacent button, and they are OK using `buttons[1].click()` (which was the first thing I came up with a day or two ago)

Comment: @JeffC Thank you.  And yes, the VMs are very costly--precisely why performance is so important.  We used to have more like 60, but a colleague and I did some refactoring over the past months to almost cut the run time in half!